# How to handle htaccess rewrite when variable has a slash inside?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite this `https://example.com/EUR/USD` to `https://example.com/details.php?code=EUR/USD` ( `EUR/USD` is the variable that can change for example `USD/GBP`, `GBP/EUR` etc.. )

beause the variable has a slash inside, following rule does not work, but if the variable does not have a slash inside (eg: `https://example.com/details.php?code=EURUSD`) it works perfect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /details.php?code=$1 [L]
```

How to handle this situation ?

EDIT: My currency htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
#RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ details.php?code=$1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sub-pattern `[^/]*` will match 0 or more of any character that is not a `/` and since you have a `/` in your GET variable this won't work.

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Z/]+)/?$ details.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Take note of 2 `RewriteCond` lines for 2 conditions that mean don't execute this rule for a real file and real directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This seems to works to a point, but the style css is not loading with this if the variable has / inside, if no / inside, css loads normally.

The problem is, my website is looking for css files in example.com/EUR/css when the variable is EUR/USD for example instead of looking in example.com/css

Comment: `style css is not loading with this if the variable has /` That is not due to this rule. That is because you are using relative links for your css. To fix, add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: Also tried that but that converts to another error:
TRL:22 Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://example.com/EUR/css/bootstrap.min.css"

I also tried to change css loading style from style.css to /css/style.css with no luck

Comment: Try complete .htaccess from my updated answer now.

Comment: still having problems with variables with slashes. I have the base code in index.php and still getting errors like :
TRL:22 GET https://example.com/USD/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404

still looking in USD folder for those files.

Comment: Is your css is path being loaded after `/USD/` that means 1. You are still using relative path not absolute one. 2. `<base href="/" />` is included in your `head` section of HTML

Comment: Shouldn't be it in the head section ? Yes I have that in head section, it is wrong ?

Comment: It is there but not working. I will try to solve this and post my finding here. Thanks very much for your effort and help.

Comment: Try including css as `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">` (it starts with a `/`)

Comment: Found my mistake, I was adding the base code to index but nut details page. My bad. Worked like charm.